# The open set has only one parametrization

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $U\in \mathbb R^n$ an open set. Thus we can take the identity map $\operatorname {Id}_U:U\to U$ to be a parametrization. My question is why this is the *only* parametrization of $U$. It seems easy but I couldn't prove it formally.

**Definition of a parametrization:**

A parametrization of class $C^k$ of a set $V\subset \mathbb R^n$ is an homeomorphism $\varphi:V_0\to V$ which is an immersion of class $C^k$ as well, defined in the open set $V_0\subset \mathbb R^m$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not. For a simple example, take $a \in \mathbb R^n$; then $f(x) = x + a$ is another one.

Comment: That's weird. I'm reading a book which says there is only one parametrization.

Comment: Does $x+a$ have to be in $U$?

Comment: @user42912, perhaps your book uses an uncommon meaning for the word "parametrization". Perhaps you could post (a screenshot of) an excerpt?

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: @user42912, with that definition, my function (with the appropriate domain and codomain) is indeed a parametrization. I think there may be a small error in your book, or perhaps you misread about the identity being the *only* parametrization.